# Applying function to specfic rows of given column based on values in another column

Tags: r

Apologies, I assume there is probably a very simple answer that I have not been able to workout.

I have a table that I have modified. I would like to interpolate the population for Years=2010:2020 only. The table only includes 1 country, but the table has 16107 rows.

I know the interpolation equation is: `mutate_at(vars(population, gdp.x), na.approx, method="linear"`

I tried apply: `apply(ssp[5,6], ssp[2]==2010:2020, mutate_at(vars(population, gdp.x), na.approx, method="linear"))`

```
Groups:   Country [177]
   Country      Year Model           Scenario       population   gdp.x SSP   Version Date   Series.Name                   Series.Code  Country.Code gdp.y
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>           <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>                         <chr>        <chr>        <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan  2010 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       28.0  0.0159 SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 2 Afghanistan  2011 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 3 Afghanistan  2012 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 4 Afghanistan  2013 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 5 Afghanistan  2014 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 6 Afghanistan  2015 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       31.8  0.0206 SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 7 Afghanistan  2016 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 NA                            NA           NA            NA  
 8 Afghanistan  2017 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 GDP growth, constant 2010 USD NYGDPMKTPKDZ AFG            2.7
 9 Afghanistan  2018 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 GDP growth, constant 2010 USD NYGDPMKTPKDZ AFG            1.8
10 Afghanistan  2019 OECD Env-Growth SSP2_v9_130325       NA   NA      SSP2  v9      130325 GDP growth, constant 2010 USD NYGDPMKTPKDZ AFG            2.9
# ... with 16,097 more rows
```

dput of first 20 rows

```
structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 
2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029), Model = c("OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", 
"OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", 
"OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", 
"OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", 
"OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth", 
"OECD Env-Growth", "OECD Env-Growth"), Scenario = c("SSP2_v9_130325", 
"SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", 
"SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", 
"SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", 
"SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", 
"SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325", "SSP2_v9_130325"), population = c(27.962207, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 31.82735098, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36.142924, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 40.89646358, NA, NA, NA, NA), gdp.x = c(0.01593680064, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02062235783, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02575387325, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03327524539, NA, NA, NA, NA), SSP = c("SSP2", 
"SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", 
"SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2", 
"SSP2", "SSP2", "SSP2"), Version = c("v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", 
"v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", 
"v9", "v9", "v9", "v9", "v9"), Date = c("130325", "130325", "130325", 
"130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", 
"130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", "130325", 
"130325", "130325", "130325"), Series.Name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "GDP growth, constant 2010 USD", "GDP growth, constant 2010 USD", 
"GDP growth, constant 2010 USD", "GDP growth, constant 2010 USD", 
"GDP growth, constant 2010 USD", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Series.Code = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NYGDPMKTPKDZ", 
"NYGDPMKTPKDZ", "NYGDPMKTPKDZ", "NYGDPMKTPKDZ", "NYGDPMKTPKDZ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Country.Code = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gdp.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.7, 
1.8, 2.9, -5.5, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(Country = "Afghanistan", .rows = structure(list(
    1:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't mix `dplyr` and base R syntax.
- `mutate_at` has been superseded you can now use `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

ssp %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(across(c(population, gdp.x), ~if(first(year) %in% 2010:2020) 
                na.approx(., method="linear") else .)) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hi ronak. Thanks for this. However I am still unable to define the years that i would like to carry out the interpolation. This carries out the interpolation for all years (2010:2100). Thanks

Comment: For all other years do you want to keep the values as it is? Updated answer might help.

Comment: I would like to keep the rest of the values - which are mostly NA. However, your solution still does not appear to be working. Possibly something in the syntax i don't understand?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you provide a subset of your data in a reproducible format (using `dput`) using which I can test my solution?

Comment: I copied the first 20 rows of the main columns for this question into a table above - sorry not sure how to use dput.

Comment: You should copy it in a way which makes it reproducible and easy to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out:

I carried out the population interpolation for the full dataframe using

```
 mutate_at(vars(population), na.approx, method="linear")
```

For the gdp, which I wanted to interpolate for only specific years, I used case_when:

```
 ssp<-ssp%>%mutate(gdp = case_when(Year>=2010 & Year<=2020 ~ na.approx(gdp)))
```